# i18n load translations from s3bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, i18next, i18next-http-backend

I am using the `i18n` module in my react app which is hosted as an app (which I will refer to as live app) on `S3` and has `cloudfront` sitting in front of it.

I want to store the s3 url in a config file as to avoid having it hardcoded in my app so that I can work against translation files stored locally in the `public/locales` folder when I'm developing.

Initially I had my backend options set-up so that it would always try and look up the files in the `locales` path. And this worked locally but stopped working on S3 although the locales folder was present in the S3 bucket. I also noticed that no request was being sent from the app to retrieve the translation files.

```
backend: {
    loadPath: 'locales'
  }
```

I then decided to upload the translation files to another S3 bucket and host them there to see if this would fix the issue.
I changed my config to hardcode the s3 bucket path. This worked both locally and on the live app. But this means that I can't use my config file to determine the loadPath option.

```
 backend: {
    loadPath: '<myhardcoded-s3-bucket-url>/{{lng}}/translation.json',
    crossDomain: true
  }
```

I then thought I could construct the url in place as so:

```
/*global AWS_CONFIG */
/*eslint no-undef: "error"*/
...
...
...
backend: {
    loadPath: `${AWS_CONFIG.aws_app_translations_path}/{{lng}}/translation.json`,
    crossDomain: true
  }
```

Strangely again this worked locally when `AWS_CONFIG.aws_app_translations_path` was both `http://localhost:3000/locales` and `<myhardcoded-s3-bucket-url>`.
However once I pushed it live, it failed again. This time making a request to `https://<my-apps-base-path>/undefined/en-GB/translation.json` for example. So it's trying to use the app path and append what I have defined in `loadPath`.

I then saw that I could have `loadPath` as a function to construct my url. This didn't work for the live app either, but again worked locally.

```
backend: {
    loadPath: function (lng) {
      return `${AWS_CONFIG.aws_app_translations_path}/${lng}/translation.json`
    },
    crossDomain: true
  }
```

This is my entire `i18n` file

```
/*global AWS_CONFIG */
/*eslint no-undef: "error"*/
import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";


const options = {
  order: ['navigator', 'localStorage'],
  caches: ['localStorage'],
  fallbackLng: "en-GB",
  debug: true,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
  },
  backend: {
    loadPath: function (lng) {
      return `${AWS_CONFIG.aws_app_translations_path}/${lng}/translation.json`
    },
    crossDomain: true
  }
}

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init(options);

export default i18n;
```

What could explain this odd behaviour? Am I missing configuration here?

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: No, no errors in the console apart from what I mentioned in the question. Missing key for all the item on that page

Comment: sounds like CORS issue, check that s3 returns the relevant headers

Comment: Except that I have CORS rules set to allow requests from my live app to the S3 bucket and as I have mentioned in my question, the url formed to send the request is `https://<my-apps-base-path>/undefined/en-GB/translation.json`

Comment: Do you see the json file it self? is s3 return the proper content-type?

Comment: The endpoint `https://<my-apps-base-path>/undefined/en-GB/translation.json` doesn't exist. I don't have a path `undefined`.
No JSON file is returned at all.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your responses in the comments, looks like you are missing the translation part, and it pre-appending `undefined` as a namespace in the url.

Try this:

```js
// i18n

const options = {
  order: ['navigator', 'localStorage'],
  caches: ['localStorage'],
  fallbackLng: "en-GB",
  debug: true,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
  },
  backend: {
    loadPath: function () {
      return `${AWS_CONFIG.aws_app_translations_path}/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json`
    },
    crossDomain: true
  }
}
```

Based on the `loadPath` config doc:

> path where resources get loaded from, or a function
> returning a path:
> function(lngs, namespaces) { return customPath; }

> **The returned path will interpolate lng, ns if provided like giving a static path**

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my question, i have already tried that. But didn't have the namespace as that is always `translation`

Comment: What happens when you are using the code I've gave you? may be you should specify defaultNS to `translation`

Comment: This is the url constructed when sending the request `https://<this is the base url of my app>/undefined/en-GB/translation.json` do you see how it should not be using the base url of my app as this is not the value defined in the config file for `AWS_CONFIG.aws_app_translations_path`. Also there is the value of `undefined` in the url which should not be there either.

Comment: Yeah, lets make SO enable us to chat, it will be much more convenient

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217745/discussion-between-felixmosh-and-hyprstack).

Answer (score 0):

Once I changed the way I was importing the config file it worked. I am guessing there is a loading issue on live, but having changed my i18n file from

```
/*global AWS_CONFIG */
/*eslint no-undef: "error"*/
import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";


const options = {
  order: ['navigator', 'localStorage'],
  caches: ['localStorage'],
  fallbackLng: "en-GB",
  debug: true,
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
  },
  backend: {
    loadPath: function (lng) {
      return `${AWS_CONFIG.aws_app_translations_path}/${lng}/translation.json`
    },
    crossDomain: true
  }
}

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init(options);

export default i18n;
```

to

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import {config} from './config';

const {aws_app_translations_path} = config;


const options = {
  order: ['navigator', 'localStorage'],
  caches: ['localStorage'],
  fallbackLng: "en-GB",
  debug: true,
  defaultNS: 'translation',
  load: 'currentOnly',
  interpolation: {
    escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
  },
  backend: {
    loadPath: (lng, ns) => {
      return `${aws_app_translations_path}/${lng}/${ns}.json`;
    },
    crossDomain: true
  }
}

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init(options);

export default i18n;
```

Fixed it. Initially `AWS_CONFIG`  was being returned as undefined despite working for the rest of the entire app. Changing the config file to live in the root directory of the project and the way it was imported solved the issue.